# Error: Required: Image, Found:Image & Parcelable

Tags: java, android, parcelable

[image]

While trying to get multiple selected images from gallery,  there is a compatible issue as shown in screenshot when i use image array list. What could be the solution?

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
            return;
        if (requestCode == ConstantsCustomGallery.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            //The array list has the image paths of the selected images
            ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(ConstantsCustomGallery.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);


            for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(images.get(i).path));
                // start play with image uri

            }
```

Comment: Are you using any library as Image Picker ? Because ``Image` class does not implements `Parcelable`. Make the right Import and you will be good to go .

Comment: @ADM, Yes, i am using lib. But this is the syntax they have given., https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in comments You need to import the right `Image` .

```
import in.myinnos.awesomeimagepicker.models.Image;
```

instead of

```
import android.media.Image;
```